# How secure is my scripting code using windows encryption?

Tags: windows, php, apache

I have a client that saw an application that I developed and wanted the software for their business. The application is written in PHP and MySQL.

They said that their internet connection is too unstable to reliably have it hosted normally and asked if we could have it hosted in their office.

I decided that I will only sell them the functionality for use and not for reselling, modifying or redistribution. I also intend on having them sign contract not to resell, modify or redistribute.

To make sure that they cannot copy the code I encrypted the application folder with EFS and set up the Apache to log in as the only admin user. This PC will be hosting the application in their office and they will not get any credentials to log into that PC.

<strike>How secure is this setup so that my client cannot copy my php code?</strike>
Is there any other vulnerabilities I should be aware of and fix if possible?

Comment: Could anyone please elaborate why question and answer was down-voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d comment if I had the points, but in my opinion that’s pretty secure, you can also make a basic key logger in that computer (or install one) that records incorrect password attempts in a file and sends the file has an email to you when it gets internet or you can just get the file if you go there, just to see if someone tried to enter or successfully entered to computer, you can also close all ports in hat computer that you won’t use, something like that.

Comment: I do not intend to ever log into the machine again, but if I do I will wipe it and reload everything just to be sure.

Comment: Would you mind fixing that* typo, and also remove keylogger and rather say "record incorrect password attempts" due to keylogger having negative connotations. Will mark as correct if no other answer comes around by tomorrow.

Comment: @Nightwolf i edited